# Can I Read A Formula Field's Logic With Apex?

Tags: apex, formula-field, metadata

I have a test class that iterates through a bunch of "educational programs my company offers" and makes sure that each program is properly embedded in our org's schema.

*(I've got a utility class that stores the API names, picklist strings, etc. to expect - the test class makes sure that the "expected" values are actually there.)*

I'd like to add a test to ensure that a certain string representing each program appears in the definition of a given formula field.  I always forget to update that formula field when we offer a new program.

**Is there a way to use Apex to fetch a textual representation of a formula field's formula?**

---

*[Note - this is NOT about recomputing the value.  This is about inspecting the code behind the formula.  Not a duplicate to `.recalculateFormulas()` questions.]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `DescribeFieldResult` class has a method named [`.getCalculatedFormula()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_getCalculatedFormula).